# Bamboo - how to set build numbers with WIX

Tags: msbuild, wix, bamboo

My project have just gone over to using Bamboo to create our ms build from the TFS Server. We can get Bamboo to create our MS Builds, but our Installers use WIX. Now in the WIX Product file we use the PRODUCT_VERSION variable which set the build number each time a build is kicked off, and in TFS days this number also auto incremented.

I am failing to find away within Bamboo where I can get it to set this value in the format of 1.0.0.234, with the last number being incremented. Further, I need to set the final number to continue from our last build number

Is there away of doing this?

Comment: In Windows Installer in general, it is _possibile_ to format a product version that way. However, it might not have the effect that you want. ["Windows Installer uses only the first three fields of the product version"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/productversion). (It does write the full version in various places but it's not involved in upgrade decisions.)

Comment: I think we need some more information on your build process. What format is the Bamboo version number in outright?

Comment: @TomBlodget Though it's possible to use all 4 fields of the version number in upgrade decisions by writing a custom action. E. g. configure the `Upgrade` table such that equal or older existing versions will be replaced and use the custom action to do a version comparison using all 4 fields to block upgrade if the existing version isn't lower than the version to be installed.

Comment: It's also possible to write a FindRelatedProductsEx  custom action and coach MSI into allowing all four fields to be evaluated as part of a Major Upgrade.